# How to show ONLY filtered data when publishing the sheet?

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am importing some data (CSV file from URL). And I am using this script to update data whenever the source gets updated  :

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {

  // Provide the full URL of the CSV file.
  var csvUrl = "https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

After I filter my data in google spreadsheets and every time the source gets updated, the filtered data are not filtered anymore!. I want to publish the sheet with filtered data only

My question is: **After importing and filtering the data, How can I keep my filter on the data even when the source gets updated?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal as follows.

- You have a Spreadsheet installed the basic filter.
- When you update the Spreadsheet by your script, you want to continue to use the existing basic filter.

In this case, how about reinstall the basic filter by copying the existing basic filter? When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {
  // Provide the full URL of the CSV file.
  var csvUrl = "https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // --- I added below script.
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  var range = filter.getRange();
  var criteria = [];
  var start = range.getColumn();
  var end = start + range.getNumColumns() - 1;
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    var criterion = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(i);
    if (criterion) criteria.push({col: i, c: criterion.copy()});
  }
  filter.remove();
  // ---

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  // And, I added below script.
  criteria.forEach(({col, c}) => range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(col, c));
}
```

#### References:

- [getFilter() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getfilter)
- [createFilter() of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createfilter)

Comment: @Tanakie Thanks it works! but I have other confusion, how can I share the spreadsheet with the same filter because I will use DataWrapper for visualization. Thanks again

Comment: @Q8Bader Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?